Best way to async process a prompt request to change a code base
I want something like the following setup.  I email an address with a prompt to create an html page.  It receives the prompt processes it by hitting the openai api creating an html page from the openai response and then creating a change in a codebase.  Then it emails me back once all of that is completed.
